# How to select the single item from ng-select by using ng model in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the ng-select model but only display the [Object Object] do not display the value.

```
<ng-select [items]="vip"  type="text" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select Yes/No" [(ngModel)]="selectedVip" name="name"></ng-select>
<h6 class="h6"><span class="flag-green"></span>{{selectedVip}}</h6>
vip = [{id: 1, name: 'Yes'},{id: 2, name: 'No'}];
selectedVip: any;
```

Comment: Because you are picking an Object. If you want to display the name try {{selectedVip.name}} in your h6

Comment: but not display placeholder they display first position of array..                                    ngOnInit(): void {  this.selectedVip = this.vip[1].name;}

Comment: There is no placeholder for select, but you can make your first option that way: `<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
</select>`

Comment: it's not work.....